# How to fetch output of page as string in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to fetch output as string. I want to run webpage from my code like www.example.com after running i want to keep whole values in a string and again in next step i want to search all anchor href values from the string. But initially how will get domain ouput as string ASP.net.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to scrape another website. This may help: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Screen-Scraping-Web-Fetching.aspx